# How to create data connection using visual studio and sql compact?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

When I try to execute this code it throws an error stating sql exception was unhandled.

```
    Dim cmdString = "Select * from STUDENT"

    connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=gandharva.sdf")
    Dim command As SqlCommand

    command = New SqlCommand(cmdString, connection)

    connection.Open()

    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    While reader.Read()


        Console.WriteLine(reader("studentname").ToString())
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the db `gandharva.sdf` in the same directory as your executable?

Answer (score 0):

You must reference the ADO.NET provider for SQL Server Compact, System.Data.SqlServerCe, and use SqlCeConnection, SqlCeDataReader, SqlCeCommand etc.